# Setting up Facebook 'like' button correctly on my website

Tags: facebook-like, app-id

I have thought for a while that my settings are iffy for my facebook 'like' button.
I have a facebook business page, but 'likes' on my website seem to go to a facebook website administration page which is linked to my website via an app id. I have searched Stack Overflow and googled generally, but have never found a complete answer as to exactly why this is, just lots of conflicting information.

Now, when I look at this website admin page (on which website 'likes' are aggregated) I see that these kinds of admin pages are being depreciated and they recommend that I migrate to a proper page. I already have a page - I don't want to create another. What can I do?

Also, my set up for my like button on my website will definitely need to be changed, either way. On the debugger page the graph api shows:

```
{
  "url": "http://www.rachellucie.co.uk/",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "Unique Handmade Silver Jewellery by Rachel Lucie",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0052/8102/t/6/assets/logo.png?169"
      }
   ],
   "description": "Contemporary handmade silver jewellery by designer Rachel Lucie from     Hebden Bridge, UK. Buy necklaces, earrings and bracelets featuring semi-precious stones and     pearls direct online.",
   "site_name": "Unique Handmade Silver Jewellery by Rachel Lucie",
   "admins": [
      {
         "id": "518522457",
         "name": "Rachel Johns",
         "url": "https://www.facebook.com/rachelluciejohns"
      }
   ],
   "updated_time": "2012-11-11T21:19:44+0000",
   "id": "499586242152",
   "application": {
      "id": "122020880748",
      "name": "Rachel Lucie Jewellery Designs",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=122020880748"
   }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

As an aside, every time I 'like' a product on my website, it creates another web administration page in facebook for that product. This doesn't seem right to me!

Thanks for your time.